# itertools.product eliminating repeated elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

How can I skip the tuples which has duplicate elements in the iteration when I use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)? Or let's say, is there anyway not to look at them in the iteration? Because skipping may be time consuming if the number of lists are too much.

```
Example,
lis1 = [1,2]
lis2 = [2,4]
lis3 = [5,6]

[i for i in product(lis1,lis2,lis3)] should be [(1,2,5), (1,2,6), (1,4,5), (1,4,6), (2,4,5), (2,4,6)]
```

It will not have `(2,2,5)` and `(2,2,6)` since 2 is duplicate in here. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`itertools` generally works on unique *positions* within inputs, not on unique *values*.  So when you want to remove duplicate values, you generally have to either post-process the `itertools` result sequence, or "roll your own".  Because post-processing can be very inefficient in this case, roll your own:

```
def uprod(*seqs):
    def inner(i):
        if i == n:
            yield tuple(result)
            return
        for elt in sets[i] - seen:
            seen.add(elt)
            result[i] = elt
            for t in inner(i+1):
                yield t
            seen.remove(elt)

    sets = [set(seq) for seq in seqs]
    n = len(sets)
    seen = set()
    result = [None] * n
    for t in inner(0):
        yield t
```

Then, e.g.,

```
>>> print list(uprod([1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 4], [5, 6, 5]))
[(1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
>>> print list(uprod([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 4], [1, 5, 6]))
[(1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 2, 4, 6)]
>>> print list(uprod([1], [1, 2, 4], [1, 5, 6], [1]))
[]
>>> print list(uprod([1, 2], [3, 4]))
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

This can be much more efficient, since a duplicate value is never even considered (neither within an input iterable, nor across them).

Comment: why does this not work Tim?: `In [77]: list(uprod([0, 1],[0, 1],[2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 1],[0, 5],[7, 0, 5],[7, 0, 5],[7, 6, 0, 8, 5],[7, 6, 0, 8, 5],[7, 8, 5],[7, 8, 5]))
Out[77]: []`

Comment: The output looks correct to me:  pass the same sequences to `itertools.product()`, and there's at least one duplicate in each of the 113400 output 10-tuples.  What do you _think_ the output should be?

Comment: I'm just getting an empty list back on Python 2.7.12 for `list(uprod([0, 1],[0, 1],[2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 1],[0, 5],[7, 0, 5],[7, 0, 5],[7, 6, 0, 8, 5],[7, 6, 0, 8, 5],[7, 8, 5],[7, 8, 5]))` You not getting that?

Comment: Yes, an empty list.  There are no product tuples free of duplicates, so the list of all solutions is empty.  Do you understand why `list(uprod([1], [1]))` is an empty list?  Same thing.

Comment: I was thinking a problem subtly different than the question. Apologies

Answer (score 5):

```
lis1 = [1,2]
lis2 = [2,4]
lis3 = [5,6]
from itertools import product
print [i for i in product(lis1,lis2,lis3) if len(set(i)) == 3]
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Comment: It is a solution but as I said in the problem, this method is not efficient. Assume you have 30 lists inside of lis and first two lists are [1,0],[1,2]. It could not find any solution unless it is done with (1,1,....) part. It is very time consuming.

Comment: @genclik27 Could you please give me sample data, for which it will not work?

Comment: It will work but not efficient. Like, lis =[[1,2],[1,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9],[10,11],[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21],[22,23],[24,25],[26,27],[28,29],[30,31],[32,33],[34,35],[36,37],[38,39],[40,41],[42,43],[44,45],[46,47]]

Comment: product(*lis) will do first (1,1,...other elements) which is 2 to the power 20 iterations. Editted it should be 2 to the power 20, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

With `itertools.combinations` there will be no repeated elements in sorted order:

```
>>> lis = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(lis, 3))
[(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5), 
(2, 4, 6), (2, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]
```