# itertools.product eliminating repeated reversed tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I asked a question yesterday and thanks to Tim Peters, it is solved. The question is here;

[itertools.product eliminating repeated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744542/itertools-product-eliminating-repeated-elements)

The new question is further version of this. This time I will generate tuples inside of tuples. Here is an example;

```
lis = [[(1,2), (3,4)], [(5,2), (1,2)], [(2,1), (1,2)]]
```

When I use it in itertools.product function this is what I get,

```
((1, 2), (5, 2), (2, 1))
((1, 2), (5, 2), (1, 2))
((1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1))
((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))
((3, 4), (5, 2), (2, 1))
((3, 4), (5, 2), (1, 2))
((3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1))
((3, 4), (1, 2), (1, 2))
```

I want to change it in a way that if a sequence has (a,b) inside of it, then it can not have (b,a). In this example if you look at this sequence `((3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1))` it has (1,2) and (2,1) inside of it. So, this sequence `((3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1))` should not be considered in the results.

As I said, I asked similar question before, in that case it was not considering duplicate elements. I try to adapt it to my problem. Here is modified code. Changed parts in old version are taken in comments.

```
def reverse_seq(seq):
    s = []
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        s.append(seq[-i-1])         
    return tuple(s)


def uprod(*seqs):  
    def inner(i):
        if i == n:
            yield tuple(result)
            return
        for elt in sets[i] - reverse:
            #seen.add(elt)
            rvrs = reverse_seq(elt)
            reverse.add(rvrs)
            result[i] = elt
            for t in inner(i+1):
                yield t
            #seen.remove(elt)
            reverse.remove(rvrs)

    sets = [set(seq) for seq in seqs]
    n = len(sets)
    #seen = set()
    reverse = set()
    result = [None] * n
    for t in inner(0):
        yield t
```

In my opinion this code should work but I am getting error for the input `lis = [[(1,2), (3,4)], [(5,2), (1,2)], [(2,1), (1,2)]]`. I could not understand where I am wrong.

```
for i in uprod(*lis):
    print i
```

Output is,

```
((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\SUUSER\workspace tree\sequence_covering _array\denemeler_buraya.py", line 39, in <module>
    for i in uprod(*lis):
  File "D:\Users\SUUSER\workspace tree\sequence_covering _array\denemeler_buraya.py", line 32, in uprod
    for t in inner(0):
  File "D:\Users\SUUSER\workspace tree\sequence_covering _array\denemeler_buraya.py", line 22, in inner
    for t in inner(i+1):
  File "D:\Users\SUUSER\workspace tree\sequence_covering _array\denemeler_buraya.py", line 25, in inner
    reverse.remove(rvrs)
KeyError: (2, 1)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean an actual error? If so, could you post the error message please?

Comment: I added error message to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you unconditionally do `reverse.remove(rvrs)`, even if `rvrs` was *already* in `reverse` before you (redundantly) added it.  So insert:

```
            remove_later = rvrs not in reverse
```

before:

```
            reverse.add(rvrs)
```

and change the removal code to:

```
            if remove_later:
                reverse.remove(rvrs)
```

Then the output is:

```
((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2))
((1, 2), (5, 2), (1, 2))
((3, 4), (1, 2), (1, 2))
((3, 4), (5, 2), (1, 2))
((3, 4), (5, 2), (2, 1))
```

Unrelatedly, you can throw away the `reverse_seq()` function and write this instead:

```
            rvrs = elt[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m doing it a bit differently, using sets to get rid of the order where the order is not necessary. Actually using frozensets, so we can easily nest them.

First of all, we convert the `lis` into a list of lists of (frozen)sets, because the order of the numbers of the tuples should be ignored.

```
>>> lis = [[(1,2), (3,4)], [(5,2), (1,2)], [(2,1), (1,2)]]
>>> lis_ = [[frozenset(x) for x in y] for y in lis]
```

Next, we create the product, and then put the result in a set, so we get rid of duplicates:

```
>>> result = set(x for x in itertools.product(*lis_))
>>> result
{(frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({1, 2})), (frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({1, 2})), (frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({2, 5}), frozenset({1, 2})), (frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({2, 5}), frozenset({1, 2}))}
```

And we are already done. If you print those now, and make it a bit prettier (getting rid of the `frozenset()` part in the output, you have your result:

```
>>> for r in result:
        print([tuple(x) for x in r])

[(3, 4), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(3, 4), (2, 5), (1, 2)]
[(1, 2), (2, 5), (1, 2)]
```

---

Different solution which just filters the results from `itertools.product`:

```
>>> lis = [[(1,2), (3,4)], [(5,2), (1,2)], [(2,1), (1,2)]]
>>> seenProducts = set()
>>> for p in itertools.product(*lis):
        product = tuple(frozenset(x) for x in p)
        if product not in seenProducts:
            seenProducts.add(product)
            print(p) # print original product

((1, 2), (5, 2), (2, 1))
((1, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1))
((3, 4), (5, 2), (2, 1))
((3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my case order is important, that why I use tuples.

Comment: If the order is important, then it makes no sense that two tuples with the same items but different order are considered equal.

Comment: No, they are not considered equal. I just don't want them to be in the same sequence. I will use this data on another program as input later on. If the data has (a,b) and (b,a) at the same time, then it returns false. So, I need to eliminate these results.

Comment: @genclik27 to be fair - that is the sort of information that should be specified as part of your question to avoid getting answers that  actually answer your question, but don't quite because of some constraint or restriction you haven't mentioned :)

Comment: As I said in the question I want to go further from the previous one. I explained in the previous question everything in detail, thats why I did not mention it in here. But, since the ordering is an important constraint, so you are right. I should have been :) Sorry about that.