# How to generate itertools product without duplicates?

Tags: python, product, python-itertools

I think i list a bad example, i apologize for this, have reedited this with another example, please see this version.

i know there is a very similar question: Itertools product without repeating duplicates

but i have something different.For example:

```
a = ['add', 'sub']
b = [2,3, 'a', 'b']
c = [1,3, 'a', 'c']
list(it.product(a, b, c))  # result is:[('add', 2, 1),('add', 2, 3),('add', 2, 'a'), ('add', 2, 'c'),
#('add', 3, 1),('add', 3, 3),('add', 3, 'a'),('add', 3, 'c'),('add', 'a', 1),('add', 'a', 3),
#('add', 'a', 'a'),('add', 'a', 'c'), ('add', 'b', 1),('add', 'b', 3),('add', 'b', 'a'),
#('add', 'b', 'c'),('sub', 2, 1),('sub', 2, 3),('sub', 2, 'a'),('sub', 2, 'c'),('sub', 3, 1),
#('sub', 3, 3),('sub', 3, 'a'),('sub', 3, 'c'),('sub', 'a', 1),('sub', 'a', 3),('sub', 'a', 'a'),
#('sub', 'a', 'c'),('sub', 'b', 1),('sub', 'b', 3),('sub', 'b', 'a'),('sub', 'b', 'c')]
```

for the result:

I dont want add(a,a), as the first value == second value

i want to keep only 1 of add(3,a) add(a,3), as it is symmetric.

and my example only contains two list, but i may use 5 or more list to generate product.

i cant use cominations, because:

product(['add', 'sub', 1,2,3, 'a','b', 'c'], repeat=3) is different with product(['add', 'sub'], [2,3, 'a', 'b'], [1,3, 'a', 'c'])

something in product(['add', 'sub', 1,2,3, 'a','b', 'c'], repeat=3) is not ok for me.

i want a fast method, since my program is time sensitive.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Do there always only two lists?

Comment: The efficient process is to create your own generator: a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744542/itertools-product-eliminating-repeated-elements and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754499/itertools-product-eliminating-repeated-reversed-tuples

Comment: There are some people don't know that, please edit it in your post.

Comment: I think i list a bad example, i apologize for this, have reedited this with another example, please see this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the implementation of `itertools.product`, tweak it so it matches your requirement:

```py
def product_without_dupl(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool if y not in x] # here we added condition
    result = set(list(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), result))) # to remove symmetric duplicates
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Source:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Then the result:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]

for el in product_without_dupl(a,b):
    print(el)

#outputs:
(2, 4)
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already converted it into a list, you can make a list comprehension to filter out the tuples where the 0 index value is equal to 1 index value.

```
filtered_list = [(a, b) for a, b in unfiltered_list if a != b]

def filter_symmetry(_list):
    checked_elements = []
    if not len(_list):
        return

    for a, b in _list:
        if (b, a) not in checked_elements:
            checked_elements.append((a, b))

    return checked_elements

filtered_list = filter_symmetry(filtered_list)
```

I think this is what you want to do.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted them both sorry, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

This oughta do it:

```
import itertools


def generate_without_duplicates(*inputs):
    seen = set()
    for prod in itertools.product(*inputs):
        prod_set = frozenset(prod)
        if len(prod_set) == 1:  # all items are the same
            continue
        if prod_set not in seen:
            seen.add(prod_set)
            yield prod


a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]

for val in generate_without_duplicates(a, b):
    print(val)
```

The output is

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(3, 4)
```