# How to remove mirrors reflections values of itertools.product function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I create a cartesian product using the `itertools.product` function:

```
from itertools import product

a = list(map(list, itertools.product(list(range(2)), repeat=3)))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Then I get rid of mirrors reflections in the following way:

```
b = [] 
for k, v in enumerate(a):
    if v[::-1] not in a[:k]:
       b.append(v[::-1])
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

But can I get the same effect step by step without saving all the results of `itertools.product` in the list? For example, with the usual approach on the for loop:

```
for i in list(map(list, itertools.product(list(range(2)), repeat=3))):
    # blah blah blah
```

Because ultimately I will use large cartesian products, at least `repeat = 18`. And that is why I have to give up the approach on the lists. Unless there is another way to do it? I will be grateful for any tips.

Comment: Yes. This is quite inefficient (both in memory and time).

Comment: The dupe contains an answer from one of the best in the business.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: it is not a dupe. Here we check membership of the *reversed* list. The check can be done here without even checking other items.

Comment: Okay, if you think this question has a better answer, please add it here.

Comment: @coldspeed: no *that* question has no better answer. The optimization is specific to mirroring :)

Comment: It's hard for me to break through the recommended answer to adapt it to my goals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744542/itertools-product-eliminating-repeated-elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools

l = (list(i) for i in itertools.product(tuple(range(2)), repeat=3) if tuple(reversed(i)) >= tuple(i))
print list(l)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: shapely solution, but it still involves writing to the list, which I find rather unuseable, because as I mentioned, I will be using very large cartesian products.

Comment: and I mean to eliminate the use of writing to lists.

Comment: You wanted to avoid *(…) saving **all** the results (…)* which it does. However I updated answer to avoid saving any results.

Comment: +1 for the second approach, but IMHO you should just remove the first one; it also has terrible running time as `l` gets longer (O(n²))

Comment: @tobias_k Done.

Comment: (Would be even better with a bit of explanation, e.g. a word or two about generator expressions and how your duplicates-check works.)

Comment: time-consuming is a fact. and if in the second solution I want to add a counter in the style `count + = 1` then how do I control it so that numbering is another natural number? because now there are jumps by the fact of removing: 1,2,3,4,6,8.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski You can just wrap the generator in an `enumerate` (the generator as a whole, not the `product` within)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea for a recursive algorithm to generate only the necessary combinations (as opposed to generate the whole Cartesian product and discarding the unnecessary ones):

```
def noReflections(n, k, current=None, idx=0, symmetric=True):
    # n: number of distinct elements
    # k: sequences length
    # current: sequence being generated
    # idx: current generated index
    # symmetric: true if the chosen elements up to now are symmetric
    assert n >= 0 and k >= 0
    if n == 0 or k == 0:
        return
    if idx == 0:
        current = k * [0]
    if idx < k // 2:
        # Choose the value for current position (idx) and symmetric (idx2)
        idx2 = k - idx - 1
        for i in range(n):
            # Value for current position
            current[idx] = i
            # If all previously selected values were symmetric,
            # the symmetric position must have a value equal or greater 
            # than the current; otherwise it can take any value.
            first = i if symmetric else 0
            for j in range(first, n):
                # Value for symmetric position
                current[idx2] = j
                # Recursive call
                # Only keep symmetric flag if previously selected values
                # and the ones selected now are symmetric.
                yield from noReflections(n, k, current, idx + 1, symmetric and (i == j))
    elif idx == k // 2 and (k % 2 == 1):
        # In middle position of odd-length sequence
        # Make one sequence with each possible value
        for i in range(n):
            current[idx] = i
            yield tuple(current)
    else:
        # Even-length sequence completed
        yield tuple(current)

print(list(noReflections(2, 3)))
>>> [(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)]
```

I'm not sure this should perform better than the other answer though, because of the recursion and so on (in a couple of quick tests bot performed similarly in my machine).

Comment: I like the approach and the detailed explanation. I'm just testing the above solution on my real problem.