# How to get product without repeating elements

Tags: python

For example, for code like this

```
from itertools import product
lst = [[1,2], [2,3], [4,5,6]]
for i in product(*lst):
    print(i)
```

I get

```
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 5)
(1, 2, 6)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
(2, 2, 4)
(2, 2, 5)
(2, 2, 6)
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 3, 6)
```

but I would like to get

```
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 5)
(1, 2, 6)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)  
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 3, 6)
```

Tell me how this can be done using itertools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [itertools.product eliminating repeated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744542/itertools-product-eliminating-repeated-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `filter` step that checks that there is 3 different values in the `tuple`

```
lst = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for i in filter(lambda x: len(set(x)) == 3, product(*lst)):
    print(i)
```

Of course, the use of an `if` is also possible, performance is about the same

```
for i in product(*lst):
     if len(set(i)) == 3:
         print(i)
```

Comment: But in essence, this cycle also goes through all the values of the product(*lst). Is there a faster solution?

Comment: @uryli "goes through all the values of the product" what do you mean ? `filter` takes a generator and returns a generator. Of course a solution that work at the generation moment whould be better, but for now I don't know one

Comment: @uryli Look this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744542/itertools-product-eliminating-repeated-elements there is no better solution shown

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that i tried and it worked for me...I'm new to python coding so any tips to improve the solution are appreciated

```
from itertools import product
def uniq_tuple(test_tup):
    res = True 
    temp = set() 
    for ele in test_tup: 
        if ele in temp: 
            res = False 
            return None
        temp.add(ele) 
    return tuple(temp)
lst = [[1,2], [2,3], [4,5,6]]

for i in product(*lst):
    if uniq_tuple(i) is not None:
        print(uniq_tuple(i))
```

Edits suggested by ggaurav

```
from itertools import product

lst = [[1,2], [2,3], [4,5,6]]

for i in product(*lst):
    if len(set(i))==len(list(i)):
        print(uniq_tuple(i))
```

Output

```
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 5)
(1, 2, 6)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 3, 6)
```

Comment: You can refer the other answer. Directly checking the length of the set of the elements solves the problem. You don't have to have separate loop

Comment: but in question he didnt mention he wants tuples of length 3 only

Comment: yes, in that case you can check `len(set(x)) == len(list(x))`

Comment: ok i will update the answer...thanks for the pointers

Comment: you can directly `print(i)`, no need of `uniq_tuple` anymore